# Dual Band + Bluetooth USB WIFI Adapter install?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb

New to ubuntu 20.04.4. I want to use a wifi+Bluetooth adapter instead of ethernet cable LAN. I have a Wifi 5 driver free adapter from Realtek which is based on rtll8821CU. Vendor does not provide a Linux driver.
I downloaded a driver from github. I now have several files and documents located in build/rtl8821CU.
I need help to complete the installation of the driver?

The installation documentation that follows is confusing to me.

1. I am trying to install a usb adapter??
   One of the first steps is to check the interface name by 'ifconfig' ??
   The driver is not installed yet, the device not even plugged in yet. How can this command return a useful wireless entry??
2. there is a 'grep' command to modify an entry in the driver to identify the device prior to driver installation?? What to do if 'ifconfig' returns no wireless entry??

Note: if I plug the adapter up front and run 'lsusb'
My adapter is detected as a usb DISK with the ID 0bda:1a2b

Here is the output of 'lsusb' with the adapter plugged in a usb port.

```
jean-jacques@jeanjacques-P5QL-PRO:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:1a2b Realtek Semiconductor Corp. DISK
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
jean-jacques@jeanjacques-P5QL-PRO:~$
```

Here is the portion of the README file which is confusing to me.
Can someone validate and/or correct the section **Check The Name Of The Interface**?

Thanks in advance!

## Realtek RTL8811CU/RTL8821CU USB

Before build this driver make sure `make`, `gcc`, `linux-header`/`kernel-devel`, `bc` and `git` have been installed.

### First, clone this repository

```
mkdir -p ~/build
cd ~/build
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
```

### Check the name of the interface

Check the interface name of your wifi adapter using `ifconfig`. Usually, it will be wlan0 by default, but it may vary depends on the kernel and your device. On Ubuntu, for example, it may be named as wlx + MAC address. (https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

If this is the case, you can either disable the feature following the link above, or replace the name used in the driver by

```
grep -lr . | xargs sed -i '' -e '/ifcfg-wlan0/!s/wlan0/<name of the device>/g'
```

### Build and install with DKMS

The rest of the file omitted due to limitations...

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.